# Ubuntu 13.10 does not show up on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, 13.10

So i just downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 on my Windows 8.1 by watching this video: http://youtu.be/PK7gWIkAY7s and restarted my computer. I didn't get the Grub menu when i restarted it so i went to windows and checked for operation systems and i only got windows 8.1. The drive that i put Ubuntu on is not showing up also. Any help?

Comment: did you installed ubuntu on your hard-disk?

Answer (score 0):

I would be shocked if that actually worked.  As of right now, it is not possible.  Windows runs on NTFP format of disk partition, meanwhile Ubuntu (Linux) runs on swap, ext-4 and these structure will not work for Windows.  The only way for both of OS to be able to see each other is if partition is being preppared in FAT32 format.

Comment: so i should just wait for a newer ubuntu?